# How to print a number inside a hexagon in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 57 hexagons defined by their vertexes and I plotted them using matlab. I would like to number those hexagons from 1 to 57 and print one number in each hexagon.For example, 1 in the first hexagon and 2 in the 2nd hexagon ..etc

thanks

Comment: Could you share what have you done so far? It makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Use the vertices to calculate the locations of the text boxes and then call `text` to draw the text.

Comment: if i use a loop "mm=1:1:57", and use the command text(x,y,'mm') within the loop, it then prints the text mm  not the value of mm inside each hexagon. any idea of how to deal with this.

Comment: Use `num2str` or `sprintf` to convert the number to a character array. What you are currently doing is printing the string 'mm'.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this that you need : in = inpolygon(xq,yq,xv,yv) ?

Comment: it doesnt do what i am looking for